# What was the first school comedy?

Tags: history-of-literature, genre

Does anyone know what the earliest example of a comedy set at a school was?

I imagine there would have been written-down short humorous anecdotes about school for as long as school has existed. And there have been many works about kooky scholars (like Aristophanes’ The Clouds.)

What I want to know is what is the earliest known comedic narrative set at a school and primarily about school life.

Comment: Clarify whether you want the earliest narrative or earliest comedy.

Comment: "The Fifth Form at St Dominic's" certainly has comic moments - but is it a comedy?

Comment: The definition of comedy has changed over time. Can you pleas describe more accurately what you have in mind?